# Bringing objects from code into the Object inspector

Tags: spyder

I am running Spyder 2.1.9, and I am liking it.  I like how much information is provided by the Object inspector, but it only brings info on the various objects if I either type them into my program via the editor or directly into the Object inspector.  Is there any way to highlight an object in your code and bring up the information in the Object inspector?

Also as a secondary question.  The auto fill pop up when entering is nice (for instance if I am using the csv module and I type `csv.` into the editor it brings up all of the possible calls for that module), but doesn't work for Tkinter.  Any idea as to why this may be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your first question is negative, unfortunately. See official [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=972) on the Spyder group.

You can use `CTRL+I` on the console to invoke the Inspector from any object, and you can also use it on **functions** (but not arbitrary objects/variables) from the editor. It's a known inconsistency.

For example, type the following into your Editor window:

```
import math
x = 3.14159
y = math.sin(x)
```

Now click on the word `math` and press CTRL-I. Nothing happens. Click on the word `sin` and press CTRL-I. The Inspector will show up the documentation for `sin()`.

Now try typing the same three lines into a Python console in Spyder, and repeat. You'll see that pressing CTRL-I after clicking `math` will work.